# button em uma div com display: none não recebe evento jQuery quando é incorporado em outra div

Tags: jquery

Tenho 2 `div's`

Uma obtendo o conteúdo da outra:

```
$( "#conta" ).html( $( "#escolhaMembro" ).html()
```

a `#escolhaMembro` está com `display: none`.

Quando o **conteúdo** da `#escolhaMembro` aparece no `body` dentro da `#conta`, vem também  um `button`.

Esse `button` não está recebendo o **evento** do `jQuery`

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $("#buttonCadastrarCelulaMembro").on("click", function () {
...
```

Qual é o problema aqui?

Comment: Poderia tentar reproduzir o código em um fiddle  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao copiar o HTML de uma div para outra, estará duplicando o botão com o mesmo `id`. Dependendo da ordem dos elementos, o evento só será disparado ao clicar no primeiro botão com a id duplicada. Ou seja, se o botão com a mesma `id` for a que estiver na div oculta, o evento não será disparado ao clicar no outro botão visível. Este é um dos motivos de ser errado duplicar id's, porque o JavaScript só irá considerar o primeiro na ordem.

O que precisa fazer é trocar o `id` por `class`, porque um ou mais elementos podem ter a mesma `class`, mas não o mesmo `id`.

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
   
   $( "#conta" ).html( $( "#escolhaMembro" ).html() );

    $(".buttonCadastrarCelulaMembro").on("click", function () {
       
       console.log("botão clicado");
       
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="escolhaMembro" style="display: none;">
   <button class="buttonCadastrarCelulaMembro">Botão</button>
</div>
<div id="conta"></div>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado @SAM.